# What's really happen here?

Tags: objective-c, logical-operators, control-flow

```
 if ([self errorIsServerError:error] || [self errorIsBadRequest:error] || [self errorIsNetworkError:error]) {
    return YES;
}
```

The methods `errorIsServerError:`, `errorIsBadRequest:`, and `errorIsNetworkError:` all return the BOOL `YES` or `NO`.

But I don't understand the syntax. Is it:

```
if (YES || YES || YES) { return YES; }
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

|| is the equivalent to saying 'or'. So your code is returning true if any of the values are true. This is what it's saying :

```
if ([self errorIsServerError:error] or [self errorIsBadRequest:error] or [self errorIsNetworkError:error])
```

If any of those are true then

```
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Each of those returns `YES` if that particular categorization applies to the given error. If the error is a server or network error, or a bad request, the method will return `YES`.

You could look at it like this:

```
if ([self errorIsServerError:error]) {
  // The error is a server error
  return YES;
} else if ([self errorIsBadRequest:error]) {
  // The error is a bad request
  return YES;
} else if ([self errorIsNetworkError:error]) {
  // The error is a network error
  return YES;
}
```

In either case, it will return yes if the error is any of those types. It will also return `YES` if it is two or all of those types (`||` is the logical (inclusive) "or" operator).

If it's none of the types, your method will continue until it hits another return statement.

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear what you're asking, but in general, you're probably expecting *none* of those errors to come through, meaning this `if` condition will evaluate false and your program can go on its way.